# Create preg_match for password validation allowing (!@#$%)

Tags: php, regex, passwords, preg-match

I would like to create a `preg_match` function to validate my passowrds, but I'm not sure how to write it to allow the following special characters to be used: `!@#$%`.

```
if(!preg_match(?????)$/', $password))
```

Here are my password rules that I want to work into the regex:

- May contain letter and numbers
- Must contain at least 1 number and 1 letter
- May contain any of these characters: `!@#$%`
- Must be 8-12 characters

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: please consider allowing longer passwords i prefer mine to be 20 + characters long, and it wont hurt you to allow this. I don't understand sites that have a max length - you store them hashed so what's the problem?

Comment: @Dragon I've increased the max to 50 characters. It is a simple site and I guess I was just thinking 8-12 character would be easier for people to remember and less likely to need to get their password reset. But like you said, with the password being encrypted, it really isn't that big of a deal.

Comment: i let lastpass remember all my passwords for me :-)

Comment: 8-12 is still short enough to brute force fairly easily though. While they work well against causal cracking attempts, 90% of 16 character passwords can be cracked in in under an hour using modern hybrid brute force techniques (which are made even easier if you know the max password length and character scope); so, I would suggest an upper limit of 32-64 characters and possibly incorporating 2-factor authentication, especially if this is meant to protect any kind of particularly sensitive data (PPI, PCI, HIPPA, etc).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I think this should look like that:

```
if(!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{8,12}$/', $password)) {
    echo 'the password does not meet the requirements!';
}
```

Between start -> `^`
And end -> `$`
of the string there has to be at least one number -> `(?=.*\d)`
and at least one letter -> `(?=.*[A-Za-z])`
and it has to be a number, a letter or one of the following: !@#$% -> `[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]`
and there have to be 8-12 characters -> `{8,12}`

As user557846 commented to your question, I would also suggest you to allow more characters, I usually (if i use a maximum) take at least 50 :)

btw, you might want to take a look at [this regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks! This is working for me. And thank you for explaining each part of it. That really helps me understand this better. I also explored the tutorial you suggested and that looks like a great resource for next time I'm dealing with regex. And I've made the max 50 characters.

Answer (score 13):

```
preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@#\-_$%^&+=§!\?])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9A-Za-z@#\-_$%^&+=§!\?]{8,20}$/',$password)
```

- at least one lowercase char
- at least one uppercase char
- at least one digit
- at least one special sign of @#-_$%^&+=§!?

Comment: Thomas's answer is better explained than r3bel's.

Comment: /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[.*@#\-_$%^&+=§!\?])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9A-Za-z.*@#\-_$%^&+=§!\?]{8,20}$/     it will work if I add . and *

Answer (score 3):

I liked r3bel's answer, so I had a play with it and ended up with the following as a password-checking function:

```
function password_strength_check($password, $min_len = 8, $max_len = 70, $req_digit = 1, $req_lower = 1, $req_upper = 1, $req_symbol = 1) {
    // Build regex string depending on requirements for the password
    $regex = '/^';
    if ($req_digit == 1) { $regex .= '(?=.*\d)'; }              // Match at least 1 digit
    if ($req_lower == 1) { $regex .= '(?=.*[a-z])'; }           // Match at least 1 lowercase letter
    if ($req_upper == 1) { $regex .= '(?=.*[A-Z])'; }           // Match at least 1 uppercase letter
    if ($req_symbol == 1) { $regex .= '(?=.*[^a-zA-Z\d])'; }    // Match at least 1 character that is none of the above
    $regex .= '.{' . $min_len . ',' . $max_len . '}$/';

    if(preg_match($regex, $password)) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Max/Min lengths are default or adjustable, each requirement is default on, but can be switched off, and I wanted to support any symbols so the last requirement is "anything that isn't one of the above types", rather than a fixed set of symbols.

Answer (score 2):

I have developed a complete regex for a bit more complex check

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[ !#$%&'\(\) * +,-.\/[\\] ^ _`{|}~\"])[0-9A-Za-z !#$%&'\(\) * +,-.\/[\\] ^ _`{|}~\"]{8,50}$/
```

Basically I check for the password to have 1 digit, 1 capital, 1 lower and 1 special character. I hope this helps someone looking for a regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[!@#$%])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]
{6,15}$/',($_POST['password']))) {
    $message='Password must contain 6 characters of letters, numbers and 
    at least one special character.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with my drupal custom form in `hook_form_validate` here the password should be 6 characters of letters, numbers and at least one special character.

```
<?
if (!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[!@#$%])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{6,15}$/', $form_state['values']['pass'])) {
    form_set_error('pass', t('Password must contain 6 characters of letters, numbers and at least one special character.'));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

### A different way

Let look different to this, I believe that users can use all of the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) valid characters `(32 < ascii_code < 127)` in the password and created a function that checks all the characters that are is in ASCII table!

```
function check($pass, $i = 0){
     if(strlen($pass) > $i)
         return (0rd(pass[$i]) > 32 and 0rd(pass[$i]) < 127) and check($pass, $i + 1);
}
```

### Usage

```
if(!check($_POST["password"])){
    echo "password is wrong";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Look up character classes, a basic feature of regular expressions.

Comment: This is borderline not an answer, especially compare to the accepted answer. Maybe you could expand it rather than just telling someone to search for something. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{8,12}$/', $password)) {
    echo 'the password does not meet the requirements!';
    }
```

In the above statement.. what possible password thus exist?.

Comment: please help me..because i entered different character but it does't exist.."the password does not meet the requirements!

Comment: if(!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{8,12}$/', $password)) {
    echo 'the password does not meet the requirements!';
    }

Comment: in above statement... is thr any body can give me a password that fit to my "preg_match password"..  because i entered dffernt combination of password but it cant submit..