# Text validation requiring special characters, numbers, capital and lowercase leters

Tags: php, regex, validation

I am having trouble with a text validation function. I need it to make sure a password has at least 1 number, one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter, no spaces, and one character that isn't a number or letter. My code so far:

```
function validatePassword($Password)
{
    if (preg_match("/[!-/0-9A-Za-z]/", $Password)==1)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

right now, it displays everything as invalid. I am also recieving the error:

```
"Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '0' in /jail/home/ds0005/html/project1/p1s5.php on line 32"
```

If it helps, the rest of my code is listed below:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

    $Passwords = array(
    'Pas$word1',
    'Pas$word2',
    'Pas$word3',
    'Pas$word4',
    'pas$word1',
    'PAS$WORD1',
    'Password1',
    'Pas$word',
    'Pas$word 1',
    'Pas$word1234567890',
    'P$wd1');

    function validatePassword($Password)
    {
        if (preg_match("/[!-/0-9A-Za-z]/", $Password)==1)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    foreach ($Passwords as $Password)
    {
        if (validatePassword($Password) == false)
        {
            echo "<p>The password <em>$Password</em> does not appear to be valid.</p>";
        }
    }
    echo "<p>Processing has completed.</p>";
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (preg_match("/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])[0-9A-Za-z!-\/]{1,}$/", $Password)==1)
```

See here for more info:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11874336/1512654

Answer (score 1):

Regexes aren't really the best tool for this kind of job, but here you go anyway.

Your requirements are literally expressed like so:

```
^(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?\p{Ll})(?=.*?\p{Lu})(?!.*?\s)(?=.*?[^\p{L}\d])
```

[regex101](http://regex101.com/r/tL8zB3/1)

I think it'd be better to do these checks yourself without regex though.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if (!preg_match('/([a-z]{1,})/', $value)) {
    // atleast one lowercase letter
}

        if (!preg_match('/([A-Z]{1,})/', $value)) {
    // atleast one uppercase letter
}

if (!preg_match('/([\d]{1,})/', $value)) {
    // altelast one digit
}

if (strlen($value) < 8) {
             // atleast 8 characters length

}

?>
```

Comment: What about special characters, that's giving me the hardest time. Is there anything that includes all of those?

Comment: @KingDave212 special characters could just use a negated character class:  e.g **[^A-Za-z0-9]**

Answer (score 0):

You might have to escape the forwardslash character like this:

```
preg_match("/[!-\/0-9A-Za-z]/", $Password)
```